# Module no longer works after moving to gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I had a module `Voltaire` that works great. And in my articles controller, I had a method that increases the user's reputation by the amount passed into the parameters.

I decided to make the module provided by a gem. I have since removed the module from my application_controller.rb file, and made it its own gem, pushed to github, and bundle installed it:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  include Voltaire

  def upvote
    @article.upvote_by current_user

    voltaire_up(1, :reputation, @article.user_id)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def downvote
    @article.downvote_by current_user

    voltaire_down(1, :reputation, @article.user_id)
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

When I use any of the methods from the module, I get `` undefined method `voltaire_down' `` where it worked before.

I have also tried removing the `include Voltaire` from the controller, but this is still not working.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a folder called `voltaire` in your project?

Comment: There's one in the gem lib directory. The structure is like lib/voltaire/voltaire.rb

Comment: Can you share the link to the gem?

Comment: For sure. [https://github.com/ddonche/voltaire](https://github.com/ddonche/voltaire). I added the self. to the methods in there, but that didn't work so I'm going to take it off.

Comment: Hmm. Works fine on my end. Only reason I can think of is if you already have a module named `Voltaire` defined in your application. If you have a folder named `voltaire`, Rails will create that module while autoloading the `Voltaire` constant.

Comment: Thanks for testing it out. I'll keep playing with it. I thought I had it working, but it turns out I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work was to put `include Voltaire` at the top of the controller. I was under the impression that rails did this automatically, but I tried the gem on two separate apps and this is the only way it will work.

**EDIT**

I managed getting this to function properly after some of the comments. In the gem's file where my module is, I just included this. Now rails includes it into the controller and it works perfectly.

```
if defined? ActionController::Base
  ActionController::Base.class_eval do
    include Voltaire
  end
end
```

Comment: Rails loads the gem automatically, but doesn't help you `include` it. Most related gems have a line loading it into `ActionController::Base`. Eg. https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb